# Which imputation technique to use for filling missing population data based on 3 categorical columns?

Tags: python, missing-data, imputation

**I am fairly new to data science. Apologies if the question is unclear.**

```
**My Data is following format:** 
    *year   age_group       pop     Gender  Ethnicity
0   1957    0 - 4 Years     264727  Mixed   Mixed
1   1957    5 - 9 Years     218097  Male    Indian
2   1958    10 - 14 Years   136280  Female  Indian
3   1958    15 - 19 Years   135679  Female  Chinese
4   1959    20 - 24 Years   119266  Mixed   Mixed*
.
.
```

.
.

Here Mixed means Both Male & Female for gender and Indian & Chinese & others for Ethnicity
where as pop is the population

I have some rows with missing values like the following:

```
    year    age_group       pop   Gender    Ethnicity
344 1958    70 - 74 Years   NaN   Mixed     Mixed
345 1958    75 - 79 Years   NaN   Male      Indian
346 1958    80 - 84 Years   NaN   Mixed     Mixed
349 1958    75 Years & Over NaN   Mixed     Mixed
350 1958    80 Years & Over NaN   Female    Chinese
.
.
.
```

These can't be dropped or filled with mean/median/previous values.

I am looking for any cold deck/any imputation techniques which would allow me fill the pop based on the values in year, age_group, gender and ethnicity.

Please do provide any sample code or documentation that would help me.

Comment: What are you using the data for?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You might want to build a model to help predict the missing values. In particular since you say you want imputation based on values from other columns. If you are familiar with scikit learn library https://scikit-learn.org/stable/ , you can experiment with the models there. Best

Comment: Hi, as a general guide to imputation technique, this note might be useful http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/missing.pdf.  Best

Comment: I don't think I understand. How does the information about year, age group etc. give me any useful information for guessing the population? Why does it make any value for population more or less likely?

Comment: Hello @KarlKnechtel , suppose in 1958 we are missing total indian population for the age group 70-75. But we have information regarding other ethnicities and total population in that year. Which would be give me the total indian population by arithmetic functions. I am wondering if there is any imputation that I can use which can do the same.

Comment: hello @mackdelany I am using the data to calculate average growth of population for each age group and ethnicity over the years.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to a give a specific answer without knowing what you might want to use the data for. But here are some questions you should ask:

**How many null values are there?**

If there are a few e.g. less than 20, and you have the time, then you can look at each one individually. In this case, you might want to look up census data on google etc and make a guesstimate for each cell.

If there are more than can be individually assessed then we'll need to work some other magic.

**Do you know how the other variables should relate to population?**

Think about how other variables should relate to population. For example, if you know there's 500 males in one age cohort of a certain ethnicity but you don't know how many females... well 500 females would be a fair guess.

This would only cover some nulls, but is a logical assumption. You might be able to step through imputations of decreasing strength:

1. Find all single sex null values where the corresponding gender cohort is known, assume a 50:50 gender ratio for the cohort
2. Find all null values where the older cohort and younger cohort is known, impute this cohorts population linearly between them
3. Something else...

This is a lot of work -- but again -- what do you want the data for? If you're looking for a graph it's probably not worth it. But if you're doing a larger study / trying to win a kaggle competition... then maybe it is?

**What real world context do you have?**

For example, if this data is for population in a certain country, then you might know the age distribution curve of that country? You could then impute values for ethnicities along the age distribution curve given where other age cohorts for the same ethnicity sit. This is brutally simplistic, but might be ok for your use case.

**Do you need this column?**

If there are lots of nulls, then whatever imputation you do will likely add a good degree of error. So what are you doing with the data? If you don't have to have the column, and there are a lot of nulls, then perhaps you're better without it.

~~

Hope that helps -- good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the input. However, I can't delete this rows and they are almost 10% of entire dataset. The dataframe has around 20000 rows. Also, I can't go ahead with 50:50 since most of the missing data are from particular age group and from same year (i.e entire 1958 70-75 age group data for male, female and combined(mixed) for indians is missing.

I am using the dataset to learn but I really want to understand how to tackle this issue.

Also, I am expecting the data to be in sense such that 1958 indians pop for male + female should be equal to mixed pop of indians in 70-75 years age group.